# Email validation Regular expression is causing catastrophic backtracking

Tags: regex, email-validation

I am using the following regex for email validation

```
^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$
```

this regex is working fine for small inputs but for longer inputs (120 char) this is causing catastrophic backtracking.

Is it possible to optimize this expression?

Comment: `([\.-]?\w+)*` is the issue, as the first part is optional and it thus could be written as `(\w+)*` which is a strong hint for catastrophic backtracking. Remove the `?` after `[\.-]`

Comment: Creating your own regex for email validation is fraught with peril.  You will fail to validate `first_last+suffix@example.museum` and probably a number of other common cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: Your expression is too restrictive, please consider using something like `<input>` `type="email"` HTML5 attribute for this.

When using two subpatterns, the first being an optional pattern, inside an indefinitely quantified group, as in your `([\.-]?\w+)*`, almost always leads to catastrophical backtracking with input that does not match the pattern.

That is, when you have a lot of word characters inside user name and domain parts, and the pattern cannot match the string, the issue occurs - see [the regex failure demo](https://regex101.com/r/7fljIo/1) with `somethingverylong@hereandthereseemore-.com` string.

What you need to do is to make sure there is no such patterns like

```
( <PATTERN_MATCHING_EMPTY_STRING> <PATTERN_MATCHING_1+_CHARS>) *
```

like

```
( a? bcd ) *
( a* bcd ) +
( a? b+ ) *?
```

inside other patterns.

You can fix them by simply making the optional pattern obligatory and adjust the group quantifier where appropriate:

```
^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.\w{2,3})+$
           ^               ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7fljIo/3). Now, `[.-]` is obligatory, it matches exactly 1 occurrence of a `.` or `-`.